# How to apply 'ON CONFLICT' condition while Inserting records after SELECT statement in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Below is the SQL query of which Laravel query is required.

```sql
    INSERT INTO 'details' (id, contact) 
    SELECT DISTINCT tmp_details.id, students.contact 
    FROM 'tmp_details'
    INNER JOIN 'students' USING(name) 
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

I am not able to apply `ON CONFLICT` condition.

**I have partially converted it as below.**

```php
    $strSQL =  DB::table('tmp_details')
                ->join('students', 'tmp_details.name', '=', 'students.name')
                ->select('tmp_details.id','students.contact');
               DB::table('details')->insertUsing(['id', 'contact'], $strSql);
```

Comment: Not sure but try `insertOrIgnore`.

Comment: I tried using insertOrIgnore, but an error occurred as below:  SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: 
  column "0" of relation "details" does not exist 
  LINE 1: insert into "details" ("0", "1") values ($1, $2) on conflic... ^ 
  (SQL: insert into "details" ("0", "1") values (id, contact) on conflict do nothing)

Comment: Show your query.

Comment: DB::table('details')->insertOrIgnore(['id', 'contact'], $strSql);    //relapced only insertUsing                                                                       I am not able to insert record, may be parameter has to be an array and values are not supposed to be given in variable.

Comment: What result you are getting in `$strSQL`?

Comment: I'd look into ready solutions: https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert

Comment: upsert requires array as parameter,  as i am getting values by using JOIN so i do not direct values to put in array.                                                               Could you please help me with an example or query ?

Answer (score 1):

**Not sure about it but try this.**

```
$strSQL =  DB::table('tmp_details')
              ->join('students', 'tmp_details.name', '=', 'students.name')
              ->pluck('tmp_details.id','students.contact');

DB::table('details')->insertOrIgnore($strSql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `DB::select()` statement:

```
DB::select("
    INSERT INTO 'details' (id, contact) 
    SELECT DISTINCT tmp_details.id, students.contact 
    FROM 'tmp_details'
    INNER JOIN 'students' USING(name) 
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
");
```